# ServiceStack: How do I Serialize a nested object of Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: json, serialization, servicestack

```
"event-data":
    {
        "event": "opened",
        "timestamp": 1529006854.329574,
        "id": "DACSsAdVSeGpLid7TN03WA",
        "delivery-status": {
            "title": "success"
        }
    }
```

```
//Structure
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> EventData { get; set; } = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

```
var json = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(request.EventData);
```

So clearly this Jsonifies the object, but only at the root level. Every child object becomes riddled with \n and \t escapes... so it's just flat stringing the children.

What's the proper (Fastest) way to make this just raw nested Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the late-bound generic `Dictionary<string, object>` and `List<object>`, e.g:

```cs
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    ["event-data"] = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        ["event"] = "opened",
        ["timestamp"] = 1529006854.329574,
        ["id"] = "DACSsAdVSeGpLid7TN03WA",
        ["delivery-status"] = new Dictionary<string,object> {
            ["title"] = "success"
        }
    }
};
obj.ToJson().IndentJson().Print();
```

Prints out:

```
{
    "event-data": {
        "event": "opened",
        "timestamp": 1529006854.329574,
        "id": "DACSsAdVSeGpLid7TN03WA",
        "delivery-status": {
            "title": "success"
        }
    }
}
```

When in doubt, you can use [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) to parse any **arbitrary JSON** which will parse them in late-bound generic collections:

```cs
var dto = JSON.parse(json);
dto.ToJson().IndentJson().Print();
```

Note: JS Utils is better at deserializing unknown JSON whilst ServiceStack.Text JSON Serializer is better about deserializing into typed POCOs.

Comment: I actually have no need to deserialize at all, I just need to take the Request in from the SS post, serialize that to string and save it right to the DB. All the other work will be done on the SQL end to query the JSON directly.

Debugging a bit more, it looks like the problem is IN the request object itself. 

It's coming into the List\Dictionary with the \r\n s?
Key: "delivery-status", Value: "{\r\n            title: success,\r\n            something: {\r\n                title: nested twice \r\n            }\r\n        }"

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott It's because ServiceStack.Text is a typed serializer that doesn't know the type to deserialize it into, can you try changing the `EventData` to `object` which should tell SS.Text to delegate to `JSON.parse()` to deserialize into the collection above.

Comment: Hmm, changing to just object made the entire thing a string 

"{\r\n        event: opened,\r\n        timestamp: 1529006854.329574,\r\n        id: DACSsAdVSeGpLid7TN03WA,\r\n        delivery-status: {\r\n            title: success,\r\n            something: {\r\n                title: nested twice \r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    }"

Is there a way in the raw request to just get the pure JSON

This is the sample posted JSON provided http://bin.mailgun.net/022043bc

I just need that event-data in the database as pure json to query

Comment: You can get the raw contents by [implementing IRequiresRequestStream](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) on your Request DTO, where you can deserialize the raw JSON from your service impl